# How to improve the performance of a swf when multiple static sprites are added to the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I'm doing an application that puts tons of sprites on the screen in random positions, like throwing cards on a table, but after a while it starts to drop the fps, because all the sprites are still consuming resources. What I would like to do is adding the sprites but like an image, without them being redrawn. Is there anyway to do that?

the code looks like this:

```
var mySprite:MySprite = new MySprite();
mySprite.x = random;
mySprite.y = random;
mySprite.rotation = random;
addChild(mySprite);
```

Ps: I will not have to mess with them after they are on the screen.

Comment: Are you tweening/animating your cards before they settle into their final position?

Comment: LDMS, seemingly not, otherwise he would have to alter their tweens each frame, while he said he "doesn't have to mess with them once placed".

Comment: No, I'm not animating them, they just pop on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think `cacheAsBitmap` is what you're looking for: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap

```
var mySprite:MySprite = new MySprite();
mySprite.x = random;
mySprite.y = random;
mySprite.rotation = random;
mySprite.cacheAsBitmap = true;
addChild(mySprite);
```

It's worth reading the documentation carefully, and Googling a bit: caching a Sprite as a Bitmap doesn't necessarily provide better performance in all cases.

Comment: This is exactly what CEAFDC needs to do. Cache your sprites as bitmaps. You'll lose some control over them after you do this, but if you don't need to modify them after creation, you should be good. It should increase performance greatly

Comment: Ok, but I forgot to mention one thing, the "cards" have to appear dynamically, like a movie. This example above works for them to appear all at the same time, right?

Comment: No, you can make them appear whenever you want. You then just set the cacheAsBitmap property to true on creation. Your app will still slow down eventually, but it will take a lot more to do so.

Comment: Exactly. But to be balanced, there's a reasonably nuanced critique of cacheAsBitmap here: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=290. The docs I linked to above are, for Adobe documentation, very detailed. Without more code I can't tell you exactly what to do, but implementing cacheAsBitmap at the right time is likely to help.

Comment: Well, if you would decide to draw your sprites over a single bitmap, while you don't clear it, you will receive the same effect without any slowness.

Comment: @Vesper - Of course, there's almost always more than one way to solve any programming problem. I suspect one method is in fact a little less resource-intensive than the other, but without running tests I couldn't say for certain which. Either will probably help @ CEAFDC with his or her issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to mess, you might look towards having a Bitmap object instead of many Sprites, and instead of adding as a child, you draw() them over a bitmapData of that Bitmap, and discard. An example:

```
var mySprite:Sprite=new MySprite();
var myMat:Matrix=new Matrix();
for (i=100;i;i--) {
    myMat.identity();
    myMat.rotate(myRandom());
    myMat.translate(myRandom(),myRandom()); // set correct randoms here
    myBitmap.bitmapData.draw(mySprite,myMat);
}
```

With this, you receive a single Bitmap which has 100 identical MySprites drawn upon it. Should your MySprite class have randomization in its constructor, you can as well re-instantiate `mySprite` variable each time.

Comment: BitmapData consumes more memory and leads to poor performance. Please refer [ADOBE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7ffc.html), [flashkit](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?814354-Does-BitmapData.dispose%28%29-remove-memory-occupied-by-its-Bitmap)

Answer (score 1):

Give a look on this awesome [article](http://esdot.ca/site/2011/fast-rendering-in-air-3-0-ios-android).
I made a few changes to it returns a sprite, instead of being one.

You can read more in the article, but this class basically get the asset bitmap data, and caches it into an object. Whenever you needs other instance of that asset, you get the cached bitmap data. You can improve a lot more, when using this technique, setting [stage quality to low](http://esdot.ca/site/2012/using-stage-quality-low-to-boost-your-performance).
This technique is better than simply using cacheAsBitmap because you can use a Sprite, instead of a flat bitmap, while still having the cached bitmap data.

```
    public class CachedSpriteFactory
    {
        //Declare a static data cache
        protected static var cachedData:Object = {};        
        public static var clip:Bitmap;

        public function cacheSprite(asset:Object, scale:int = 2):Sprite
        {
            //Check the cache to see if we've already cached this asset
            var data:BitmapData = cachedData[getQualifiedClassName(asset)];
            if (!data)
            {
                var instance:Sprite = new asset();
                var bounds:Rectangle = instance.getBounds(this);

                //Optionally, use a matrix to up-scale the vector asset, this way you can increase scale later and it still looks good.
                var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
                m.translate(-bounds.x, -bounds.y);
                m.scale(scale, scale);              
                data = new BitmapData(bounds.width * scale, bounds.height * scale, true, 0x0);              
                data.draw(instance, m, null, null, null, true);
                cachedData[getQualifiedClassName(asset)] = data;
            }

            clip = new Bitmap(data, "auto", true);
            //Use the bitmap class to inversely scale, so the asset still appear to be it's normal size
            clip.scaleX = clip.scaleY = 1/scale;
            var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sprite.addChild(clip);
            //Optimize mouse children
            sprite.mouseChildren = false;

            return sprite;
        }
    }
```

---

Usage:

```
stage.quality = StageQuality.HIGH
var cacheFactory:CachedSpriteFactory = new CachedSpriteFactory();
var coolSprite1:Sprite = cacheFactory.cacheSprite(SpriteLinkageNameInLibrary, 1);
var coolSprite2:Sprite = cacheFactory.cacheSprite(SpriteLinkageNameInLibrary, 1);
stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW
```

Comment: When I try tracing the result of getBounds() of a Sprite with one Shape added to it, it gives me weird values while that Sprite can't reach the stage. This might work in later versions of Flash player than my target (10.2). This is remedied if you add it as a child and then remove when it's not needed, should you get hit with this. A nice approach, though.

Comment: @Vesper What you mean with "can't reach the stage" ?  It is suposed to work with almost versions of FP

Comment: I mean, if the "stage" property of that sprite is null. For some reason, when I have tried creating many sprites in the background to be drawn on bitmaps like this (more than one sprite per bitmap though), getBounds() gave me ridiculous values in line of (-8.0e6,-8.0e6,0,0) in the returned rectangle. As soon as I do `addChild(theSprite);` with my parent being already added to stage, it works, if the parent is not on stage, nothing changed. I wonder should I raise a question about this.